# Regex pattern syntax error with forward lookaheads on Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I have an Android application in which I'm trying to parse a small sized XML response coming from server. I have simply just used a regex for doing that, but now I'm facing a problem dealing with optional XML-tags that may or may not be present in the response's payload. My regex is declared as

```
final String regex = "^(?=.*<x>(.+)</x>)(?=.*<r>(.+)</r>)?(?=.*<e>(.+)</e>)" +
            "(?=.*<h>(.+)</h>)(?=.*<y>(.+)</y>)(?=.*<n>(.+)</n>).*$";
```

Note the question mark after the second look ahead group to have the < r > tag be optional. It is causing me an exception when compiling with Pattern.compile:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
...
12-19 10:19:21.257: E/AndroidRuntime(2342): Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 36:
12-19 10:19:21.257: E/AndroidRuntime(2342): ^(?=.*<x>(.+)</x>)(?=.*<r>(.+)</r>)?(?=.*<e>(.+)</e>)(?=.*<h>(.+)</h>)(?=.*<y>(.+)</y>)(?=.*<n>(.+)</n>).*$
12-19 10:19:21.257: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):                                     ^
12-19 10:19:21.257: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
12-19 10:19:21.257: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
12-19 10:19:21.257: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
12-19 10:19:21.257: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
```

Without the ?-quantifier it compiles just fine.

I tried also using the same pattern on Windows with desktop java (jdk 1.6.0_24) and it worked as it should (and even parsed my test payload correctly). Are there some known limitations with the native regex implementation on Android or am I just missing something here? I already read the [Android documentation regarding Pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, I wouldn't like to resort to having to use a dedicated XML parser for something as simple as this.

Comment: I'm not sure about quantified look aheads (they might not be supported), so you might try and change that part to `(?=(?:.*<r>(.+)</r>)?)` i.e. use an inner non-capturing quantified group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually can't make a lookahead optional by appending a `?`. This is a syntax error in some regex dialects (because a lookahead assertion doesn't match anything that could be quantified by the `?`).

But you can wrap the lookahead in an optional non-capturing group:

```
final String regex = "^(?=.*<x>(.+)</x>)(?:(?=.*<r>(.+)</r>))?(?=.*<e>(.+)</e>)" +
            "(?=.*<h>(.+)</h>)(?=.*<y>(.+)</y>)(?=.*<n>(.+)</n>).*$";
```

Comment: This may fix the syntax error, but I am not sure if it makes sense at all to have a lookahead that is optional?

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Thank you! And yes, I am aware that using this approach for parsing xml is somewhat unconventional. I was just a bit curious about how to pull this off using regexes. Moreover I was wondering why this would not work on Android having used the same thing at least with python and desktop Java, but as said above, dialects can differ.